# What is wrong with my Azure App Configuration endpoint?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-app-configuration

I have built two test net core mvc test apps using Microsoft tutorials.

1. Build an app that uses a connection string for using Azure App Configuration

   [Quickstart: Create an ASP.NET Core app with Azure App Configuration](http://Create%20an%20ASP.NET%20Core%20app%20with%20Azure%20App%20Configuration)
2. Build an app that uses managed identity for using Azure App Configuration (my app TestAppConfigMi)

   [Use managed identities to access App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core5x)

The first test works running locally using a connection string. The second has errors that indicate the Azure App Configuration endpoint or clientid is null.

- the endpoints are the same for both apps
- the clientid may not be correct but is present in the second app

I don't have much experience. My troubleshooting process has been:

- TestAppConfigMi project builds locally in Visual Studio
- In Azure browser launches with HTTP 500.30

Azure diagnostics

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.921.35908
.NET Version: 5.0.9
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at TestAppConfigMi.Program.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateHostBuilder>b__2(AzureAppConfigurationOptions options) in D:\a\TestAppConfigMi\TestAppConfigMi\Program.cs:line 29
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationSource.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at TestAppConfigMi.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\TestAppConfigMi\TestAppConfigMi\Program.cs:line 17
```

In Program.cs (line 29)

```
options.Connect(new Uri(settings["AppConfig:Endpoint"]), new ManagedIdentityCredential("26e962f7-1a26-4f11-84d4-3bfcdd9f7dcc"))
```

(line 17)

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

In Visual Studio AppConfig:Endpoint in appsettings.json

```
"AppConfig": {
"Endpoint": "xxxx"
```

is the same as that of secrets.json in the first working app

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings:AppConfig": "Endpoint=xxxxx"
}
```

There are two packages installed:
Azure.Identity 1.5.0
Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore 4.5.0

The debug reference is an identifier being null. Whichever way I look at it there is a value present. So I would expect a "not found" or "wrong credentials" type message. Not the app failing as it does.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the stack trace:

```
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')

at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) //<== BAM!
```

So `settings["AppConfig:Endpoint"]` must be returning null:

```
options.Connect(new Uri(settings["AppConfig:Endpoint"]),
```

Fix that and you have fixed your (current) problem.

To check your providers are runtime, just debug and inspect `settings` you will see a list of all the available providers and their resolved values, my guess is it's a typo, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Dave, besides what @TheGeneral said, please note that the ManagedIdentityCredential does not work locally. I hope my response to a similar question can be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729522/403-when-connecting-to-azure-app-configuration-using-a-managed-identity/61738355?noredirect=1#comment123303998_61738355

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral & Zhenlan Wang for your inputs.

Comment: one of the key steps that I missed with this is that you need to `.Build()` the configuration so you can use the setting to connect to azure to get more settings.  In essence it appears you have to `.Build()` the configuration twice.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem using the following changes:

Here is the Microsoft tutorial code [Use managed identities to access App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core5x)

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var settings = config.Build();
            config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                options.Connect(new Uri(settings["AppConfig:Endpoint"]), new ManagedIdentityCredential()));
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

Here is the working code running **locally** (VS Azure Service Authentication & me having System Managed Identity Data Owner & Data Reader Roles for the Azure App Configuration service) & **deployed** to Azure (App Service System Managed Identity Data Owner & Data Reader Roles for the Azure App Configuration service)

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var settings = config.Build();
                var appConfigurationEndpoint = settings["AzureAppConfigurationEndpoint"];

                config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                    {
                        options.Connect(new Uri(appConfigurationEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    });

                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
        });
```

The appsettings.json is:

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "AzureAppConfigurationEndpoint": "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.azconfig.io"
}
```

I have not examined the reasons why these changes make the difference. I should! But to be practical this is just a small module of a larger project. However I did try various combinations (trying to include as much tutorial code as possible)

I think the issue is that local development needs to be successful before cloud deployment. Therefore we need code that works seamlessly across both environments. So the use of `DefaultAzureCredential()` rather than `ManagedIdentityCredentials()` would seem preferable.

I note the Azure.Idntity docs state that the latter `ManagedIdentityCredentials()` "Attempts authentication using a managed identity that has been assigned to the deployment environment" but does not detail why the former `DefaultAzureCredential()` is only "intended to simplify getting started with the SDK by handling common scenarios with reasonable default behaviors"?

However it would seem to me that a basic tutorial, such as this one, should consider terms such as "getting started" & "simplification" to be a priority. Also the importance of seeing code working locally should not be underestimated.

I would welcome comments by anyone on these changes. In particular the way the Azure App Configuration endpoint is handled in each example.